For what $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is the system $\alpha x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1 \\ x_1 + \alpha x_2 + x_3 = -1 \\ x_1 + x_2 + \alpha x_3 = -2$
For what $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is the system $$\alpha x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1 \\  x_1 + \alpha x_2 + x_3 = -1 \\ x_1 + x_2 + \alpha x_3 = -2$$
Is solvable, and uniquely solvable respectively.
I've tried doing the gaussian elimination for this system and found that as long as $\alpha$ not -2, -1, or 1 the system will be uniquely solvable. However, i don't know what value of alpha will cause the system to have infinitely many solutions though
Any help would be appreciated

Plug in the special values for $\alpha$ and solve the resulting systems. Also: There should be a unique solution for $\alpha = -1$.

The null space has dimension two when $\alpha=1$ (and dimension one with $\alpha=-2$), so there cannot be a third problematic value. Please check $\alpha=-1$! I would be surprised if that were not a uniquely solvable system.

Okay, my bad. If alpha is -1, it would be solvable. But I still can't find the alpha value for which the system has infinitely many solutions though

@JyrkiLahtonen Did you guys find alpha for which the system has infinitely many solutions? Or was it just a trick question?

You want an $~\alpha~$ (if any) where one equation is equal to another equation times a scalar.  Please show your work, directly in the posted question, not in the comments.

I don't see how that would be a trick question. It's completely feasible for a system of equations with a parameter to never have infinte solutions.
